# LibGDX project on Mac - Launch as iOS sim. app

Tags: java, ios, eclipse, macos, robovm

I am developing game using libgdx framework and I have succesfully finished its android version. Now I am trying to finalize ios part of the project. I have setup working environment in Mac Os X, checked out project from git repository, but I have no luck running it as iOS simulator App. It seems that Eclipse does not detect it as Robovm project at all. Please see screenshot...

[image: img]

Test is sample new project that runs just fine when I run it as iOS simulator app. But piggy-ios which is ios part of my libgdx game cannot be run as iOS simulator (there is no option for it and in Run configurations Eclipse does not seem to recognize piggy-ios as an roboVM project at all. Does anybody know how to force Eclipse to run it as iOS simulator app?

Comment: I don't have domain knowledge for Eclipse, piggy-ios, and roboVM, but we did make a rather major change to the iOS Simulator in Xcode 6.  If these tools were like ios-sim and other 3rd party hacks that reverse-engineered the iOS Simulator in older versions of Xcode, they likely need to be updated to support CoreSimulator.framework (or use the simctl command line tool) in Xcode 6.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for your reply, but actually this is probably not the case. I solved situation by manually editing Eclipse project and adding  "RoboVM" nature to it. Now it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all people having similar troubles. I had to manually edit Eclipse project file and adding "RoboVM" nature to it. Now it works as expected.